# Date manipulation in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t format the date properly in VBA, Excel 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295495/cant-format-the-date-properly-in-vba-excel-2012)

I am having some issue (primarily type mismatch) with a date. What I am trying to do i get they system time and then subtract 3 days in YYYMMDD format. For example, 20121204 should return 20121203. 20121203 should return 20121130. Currently, I can get the date with:

```
Sub dateComp()
Dim todaysDate As String
todaysDate = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
Debug.Print (todaysDate)
End Sub
```

I have tried using DateAdd and its not working. DateAdd(d, -3, todaysDate)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `Format(Date-3, "yyyymmdd")` is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Debug.Print Format(DateAdd("d", -3, Date), "yyyymmdd")
```